# "var d = document;" Is it really useful?

Tags: javascript

I regularly see JavaScript code with variables like this:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.body;

w.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    ...
    d.querySelectorAll(...);
    ...
});
```

I just wonder if there is an interest in using these kinds of variables? (Other than decreasing the amount of code if there are many calls to "document" or "window")
I think the answer is no, but just in case ...

Comment: Minification ... no other good reaon

Comment: yes if you have to repeat 50x the object

Comment: but decreases readability. Also vulnerable to bugs if you have `var d` as a local var somewhere

Comment: I assume that it also can be used to access an outer scoped node if the name is taken in the local scope.

Comment: If there were no interest in this then you wouldn't "regularly see" it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. The way you are using them, no, there is no benefit because your code doesn't make use of `g` or `e`.

Your code makes these variables global and globals should be avoided. We can do this by wrapping our code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) which creates a wrapper scope around your variables. But, because there is now a layer of indirection, references to elements in a higher scope will have to be resolved by going up the "scope chain" to find their definitions.

If you were to pass references to your global (or higher scoped) objects into the smaller scope, you can increase performance slightly because you will have local references to higher scoped objects and avoid having to go up the scope chain. So, if you did this:

```
(function(w, d){
  // Within this function w and d are local references to global objects
  w.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    ...
    d.querySelectorAll(...);
    ...
  });

}(window, document));
```

then, having these declarations (actually arguments here) would make sense.

Additionally, any time you have to "resolve" an object reference, the less steps you take to resolve them, the better the performance, so while:

```
var w = window;
var d = document;
```

aren't particularly useful since both are always globally available, these

```
var g = document.body;
var e = document.documentElement;
```

are useful because you do have to look up the object stored in the `body` and `documentElement` properties and you've taken the "hit" in resolving the `body` and `documentElement` DOM objects just once, but later you can directly access them without having to resolve them again and again.

Comment: Alright, thanks you for your answer! It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful if you feel that it helps you.

Some people are using it as a shortcut to reduce the number of characters when writing a program.

To me it reduces readability and adding variables to global scope can cause some unpredicted issues.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is useful, when you write `var d=document`, you are storing the document inside this variable which makes it easier if you want to use this variable with a
`method`

Example:

```
var d = new Date()
document.write(d.getHours())
```

Here you store the `new Date()` inside the `d` variable that way it will be easier to use it somewhere else.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the question. And, no, you are not storing the document inside the variable. You are simply storing the memory address of where the object can be found. Lastly, your code could simply be written as: `document.write(new Date())`. If you don't need continued access to the object, creating a variable for it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: I always forget the first point , that the address is being stored not the document. Thank you for explaining!